# Python Pandas read_excel empty DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Can somebody explain this? My test excel contains only 1 sheet, but it seems to sit behind sheet_name=1 and what's that "1.1.1" which is behind sheet_name=0?

[image]

My Excel looks like this:

[image]

I'm using LibreOffice v6.4.7.2, saving as the suggested "Excel 2007-365 Format". Pandas is at v2.0.2 and Python at v3.11.3. All my search results claim that I should receive sheet 1 by using sheet_name=0. But I don't and I don't find any cases like this.

Comment: Your file likely contains multiple sheets. Check if a sheet is very hidden.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I asked this question yesterday after finishing work and didn't get back to this topic until now. You're absolutely correct, thank you! There was a hidden sheet named "__properties". It contains only 1 cell with the value "1.1.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BigBen is totally right, you should have a hidden sheet. You can use the following code to check the state of each sheet:

```
with pd.ExcelFile('testupload.xlsx') as xlsx:
    wb = xlsx.book
    for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[sheetname]
        print(f'{sheetname}: {sheet.sheet_state}')
```

Output:

```
Sheet1: hidden
Sheet2: visible
```

Only one visible sheet:

[image]

Comment: You can show hidden sheets in LibreOffice directly, but this is of course also a solution. Thank you guys for helping me out and sorry, I had never heard about hidden sheets and it just didn't cross my mind. Now I actually wonder why, because that feature totally makes sense ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the sheet names you may initially want to identify the available sheets, you can achieve that by passing `sheet_name=None` argument to the `read_excel` call:

```py
import pandas as pd
sheets = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

and then pass the name of sheet you want to ingest using the available keys

```py
df_sheet_2 = pd.read_excel('tests.xlsx', sheet_name=list(sheets.keys())[1])
```

#### `tests.xlsx`

*A simple file with two sheets*

[image: File structure preview]